# Check if an element has already listener

Tags: angularjs, directive, event-listener

How can I check if a specific event listener already binded to the element or not? For example:

```
myApp.directive("myDirective", function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var myListener = function () {
                alert("Hello!!!");
            };
            elem.on("click", function () {
                if (!$document.hasEvent("click", myListener)) { // Check in here
                    $document.on("click", myListener);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

How should be the `hasEvent` function? Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 1):

You can change your check to this:

```
if (!$document[0].onclick) { // Check in here
    $document[0].onclick = myListener;
}
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7mRQW/

Comment: I can work on that, thanks. But isn't there a way to see the listeners which has binded via 'bind' or 'on' methods?